# Pictures in radio button not working with IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I trying use pictures in radio button. But problem is when i running on IE9 it work fine but on IE 11 not. On my jQuery scripts i hide all radio buttons and for actions i using label's. On IE9 i can click on the picture (anywhere) and it is fine. But on IE11 i need click only on left bottom corner.

```
<div id="div_name">
    <table class="tables">
        <tr>
            <td><input type="radio" name="name"[] id="H1" value="H1" class="me_radio"><label for="H1" class="radio_label"><img src="icons/1.gif"><br>One</label></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="name"[] id="H2" value="H2" class="me_radio"><label for="H2" class="radio_label"><img src="icons/2.gif"><br>Two </label></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="name"[] id="H3" value="H3" class="me_radio"><label for="H3" class="radio_label"><img src="icons/3.gif"><br>Three</label></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>


$('#me_radio label').click(function() {
    $('#other_div label').removeClass('selected');
        .
        .// remove classes from another
        .
    $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
});
```

And CSS

```
.selected {
    background-color: #ccc;
}
```

Comment: `name="name"[]` ? What ? Also, advised to use lowercase `id`

Comment: @Raptor name="name"[] = name="real_name"[]

Comment: Do you mean `name="name[]"` ?

Answer (score 0):

Might be kind of late for this, but the workaround I have been using is

```
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=10">
```

You might have already solved this issue, but hope you found another way for it work.